# Smartsheet python API: Cannot access any attachment object attributes except for attachment name, url, and ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to access the createdAt timestamp for an attachment in Smartsheet. I created an attachment object with the get_attachment(sheetID, attachmentID) function.

When I print the object all the attributes show up with values. However when I try to return the individual value of attachmentObject.createdAt, I get an error. It works fine for the url, name, and id attributes, but none of the other ones. How do I access this value that is clearly there!!!

It's not the format of my print statements or anything, I've tried print on it's own without the string formatting, type(attribute), just declaring a variable based on it. None of it works. The error message is useless, it's just the name of the attribute. Even when I take out the try/except loop the error message is still just the attribute name.

The only thing I've found that actually works is a really hokey work around that I don't want to go with if I can avoid it.

I turn the entire object into a string, split the string on ',' to create a list. Then I split each of those values on ':' to create a key/value pair and basically create a dictionary for each item. THEN I take the string of the timestamp and turn it into a datetime object with strptime.

It works but it's really not ideal and there has to be a a way to actually access the object attributes.

```
attachment_attributes = ss.Attachments.get_attachment(res_id, attachment_id)
print(attachment_attributes)

try:
    print('ATTACHMENT CREATED AT: ' + str(attachment_attributes.createdAt))
except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR: ' + str(e))

try:
    print('ATTACHMENT NAME: ' + str(attachment_attributes.name))
except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR: ' + str(e))


CURRENT OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------
print(attachment_attributes) returns this:

{"attachmentType": "FILE", 
"createdAt": "2019-10-07T16:52:01+00:00Z", 
"createdBy": {"email": "osian@coastalmountain.ca"}, 
"id": 1410102853953412, 
"mimeType": "application/pdf", 
"name": "documentname.pdf", 
"parentId": 2876391983212420, 
"parentType": "ROW", "sizeInKb": 183, 
"url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...", 
"urlExpiresInMillis": 120000}


print of individual attributes returns this:

ERROR: createdAt //Output for the createdAt attriute
ATTACHMENT NAME: documentname.pdf //Output for the name attribute


EXPECTED RESULT FOR PRINTING attachment_attributes.createdAt:
-------------------------------------------------
"ATTACHMENT CREATED AT: 2019-10-07T16:52:01+00:00Z"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `attachment_attributes.created_at` to access that object. Python uses the convention of attribute names being in [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), all lower case and separated by underscores. The Smartsheet Python SDK follows this convention as well. Even though the JSON objects returned show [camel casing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) when working with the API directly the Smartsheet Python SDK serializes the responses to work with the snake case convention. That should let you access the attribute you need. This can be applied to all multi-word attributes. You others likely work due to them being single word attribute names.

Comment: I just became frustrated with someone who figured something out that I was trying to figure out and didn't post their solution so I figured I should just comment and say thank you you were right!!!

Comment: @MaddisonLussin Awesome. I am glad to hear this worked for you. Would you be able to mark my answer as correct here? That will allow others who come across this post to know it is a solution.